# Incrementing through object properties?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to increment ( not loop ) through object properties.  I know that objects don't guarantee ordering but I want to increment through them any ways.

For example, for an array one can do:

```
arr[index++];
```

But this does not work for an object:

```
obj[key++];
```

as I do not think the ++ operator is defined for use on keys.

I don't want to have to build a complex object structure that stores indexes with keys.  I want to do it natively.

I am well aware of the for-in structure but I want to increment as needed, not loop.

Comment: What input/output do you expect?

Comment: What made you think `obj[key++];` will work?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In recent browsers, you can use the [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) array :

```
val = Object.keys(o)[i++];
```

Detailed example :

```
var keys = Object.keys(o);
for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    console.log(key, o[key]);   
}
```

To be compatible with IE8, use this construct to iterate over keys :

```
for (var key in o) {
   console.log(key, o[key]);
}
```

If you don't want to iterate over inherited properties, use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) :

```
for (var key in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(key) console.log(key, o[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`++` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B.2B_.28Increment.29) works on any *number*: it increments the number by one.

If the properties of your object are numbers, you could certainly use `++` to iterate over them:

```
var obj = { 1: "foo", 2: "bar", 3: "baz" };
var i = 1;
console.log( obj[i++] );
console.log( obj[i++] );
console.log( obj[i++] );
```

(Of course, one problem with this is that, in general, there's no guarantee that the properties of an object, even if numeric, would have to be *consecutive* numbers.)

Now, dystroy has already pretty well answered the actual question, so I won't repeat his answer here.  I just wanted to add this bit to stress the fact that asking whether "the `++` operator is defined for use on keys" is missing the point: the `++` operator *doesn't know or care* about whether the value it's operating on is an array key or an object property name or [the answer to life, the universe and everything](http://www.google.com/search?q=answer+to+life+the+universe+and+everything).  All it cares about is whether or not it is, or can be meaningfully interpreted as, a number.